# Gitlab CI ignores script exit code other than 1

Tags: bash, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, exit-code

I'm trying to set up a GitLab pipeline, so that certain `exit_codes` are okay for a script I'm executing.
I have tried both shell and a ruby script, but both seem to have the same behaviour.

```yaml
test_job:
  stage: build
  image: ruby:3.0
  script:
    - chmod +x ci/wrap.sh
    - ./ci/wrap.sh
  allow_failure:
    exit_codes:
      - 64
```

As you can see, I am just executing the script and nothing more, my expectation would be, that the last script executed is used a the exit status for the job.

In the script I'm only calling `exit 64`, which should be a "allowed failure" in that case, the pipeline log however says that the job failed because of exit code 1:

[image: pipeline error]

How do I get GitLab to accept the exit code of this (or a ruby) script as the job exit code?

Comment: Don't post code as screenshot. It sounds like you are getting error code 1 instead of 64 from your script. Are you sure something else is not failing in there?

Answer (score 21):

I found a way to fix this problem. Apparently Gitlab Runner uses the `-e` flag, which means that any non-zero exit code will cancel the job. This can be updated by using `set +e`, but then you still need to capture the actual exit code for the job.

Using `$?` in two different lines of the configuration does not work, because Gitlab does `echo` calls in-between them.

So the exit code needs to be captured directly, example:

```
script:
  - set +e
  - ruby "ci/example.rb" || EXIT_CODE=$?
  - exit $EXIT_CODE
```

Comment: I have this same issue. Can you provide more information about where you ran `set +e`, or if you know of somewhere that is configured? Also, what happens with that if a non-allowed non-zero exit code is given? I think that'd be useful to add to your answer.

Comment: `Can you provide more information about where you ran set +e` he didn't. There is no need to if you are capturing exit status with `||`.  `if you know of somewhere that is configured?` it isn't configured. You can put `set +e` as part of your script. `what happens with that if a non-allowed non-zero exit code is given?` I do not understand "non-allowed". Any non-zero exit code is allowed, and when running under `set -e` they cause the script to terminate. You may want to read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105 .

Comment: @KamilCuk It seems that gitlab has the nasty habit of translating any non-zero exit code to 1 unless errexit is suppressed.  There's no need to do the `|| exit_code=$?` cruft, though, and it is sufficient to do just do `set +e` and then a call to `ruby`

Answer (score 4):

Here's my trick for turning off early failure and checking the result code later:

```yaml
  script:
    - set +e +o pipefail
    - python missing_module.py 2>&1 | grep found; result=$?
    - set -e -o pipefail
    - "[ $result == 0 ]"
```

This turns off early exit and runs a command that we consider to have an acceptable failure if "found" is in the error text. It then turns early exit back on and tests whether the exit code we saved was good or not.